# How to automatically convert some text into url's?

Tags: google-docs

i'm wondering is in Google Docs possibility to automatically convert some text into url's?

For example, i'd like to convert all words "Google" into [Google](https://www.google.com)

for this moment i found some workaround - first we have to replace all desired work to urls and then google doc will suggest to change it by name
[image]

but there no guarantee that name will be correct.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Yes, it's possible.. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén `Yes, it's possible` How?

Comment: for this moment i found some workaround - first we have to replace all desired work to urls and then google doc will suggest to change it by name
(i'll add this into initial question)

Comment: @SeverusSnape i told this is workaround, not solution. at least we know that it works vice versa.

Comment: @Rubén could you pls shed some light on this issue?

Comment: You already found one way, but there are others. i.e. you might use Google Apps Script, the Google Docs API, an add-on (if one already exists for what you are looking for).